# EIP-4337 key rotation

Tags: gnosis-safe

I am just having a question regarding EIP-4337 protocol regarding key rotations.

EIP-4337 let's you program different private keys ( let's say one for swap, other for sending tokens, etc..)

Do you know they way in solidity wise how can a solidity dev program those keys? Or is there any guide for it in your documentation?

Thank you and Regards,

Riki